# A first or the first after mentioning general categories

Tags: grammaticality, articles, academic-writing

In the following passage:

> Recent works have tackled the explainability shortcomings with
> different approaches. A first approach investigates to which extent an
> input feature is responsible for a decision.

I am wondering if I should use "a first" or "the first"?

Update: To clarify my text. First, I want to say that there are different approaches, then I want to describe these approaches in detail. In total, there are 3 approaches, and the 2nd sentence above is referring to the 1st.

Comment: As with many things, changing a word like an article (or a preposition) can alter the meaning of the sentence. What do you want your sentence to mean? What are you actually describing? [Please [edit] your question to add clarifying details.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach I updated the question. Is it clear enough?

Comment: 'A first approach' is fine if the ordered list you mention _hasn't been mentioned, or implied_, in the passage so far. It's like 'a first try / stab / attempt'. But once you've mentioned an ordered list that was sensibly drawn up, this demands A, B, and C, with A **the** first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say ***the** first approach*, you are entailing that the approaches are ordered, and this one is Number One, in some unspecified way -- you may think it's the best, or the worst, or the most popular, or the most obvious. You don't say.

If you say ***a** first approach*, on the other hand, you're merely saying that that's the first one you're going to consider, for your own reasons; again, you don't say.

So this is not a grammatical problem; it's a rhetorical problem. Why are you choosing this approach to start with, and what do you want the reader to know about that? Your choice.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one first approach, so the definite article ***the*** should be used.

If you said ***a first approach***, I would understand *a first (**possible**) approach*, that is, that more than one approach could be considered as claiming the first place in the explanation.

In your edit, you yourself use ***the***:

> In total, there are 3 approaches, and the 2nd sentence above is referring to ***the 1st***.

Comment: ... and that can't apply here, as OP stipulates that 3 approaches are arbitrarily (from an etic point of view) ordered, this being **the** first in the chosen ordering. But this is a question with other problems; 'explainability shortcomings' sounds unnatural, and 'I have following sentences' at best misplaced headlinese.

Comment: Indeed, but as @EdwinAshworth commented, there are no orders, so I still feel unsure if using "the first".

Comment: @lenhhoxung What Edwin stated is that you can't say "a first" since the order existing is that of your own choice.